# Accessing localhost from remote network

Tags: apache

Before I send things live, I want to test on localhost. I understand that if one has a static IP, which I do, it is possible to access localhost if it runs an apache server, which I do.

Current configurations:

XAMPP 3.2.2 (latest) with PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4.17

Right now as I type my static IP into the browser (with port 85 as port 80 is used for something else on host computer), I get Chrome error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Do I need extra configurations?

Comment: Do I need to configure Port Forwarding? just a random thought

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for this, but I found an answer. It is indeed done by adding the current localhost port to Port Forwarding in router control panel (if its not an automatic action).

But this may serve as help to those who find themselves in the same situation in the future.